# How to limit user to choose just two enums from list using Java Streams?

Tags: java, enums, stream

I have an enum class from which user can choose up to 2 options.
If he chooses more than 2 an error message should be displayed.

I would like to do this using Java streams. I am still trying to figure out how they work.

So far I came up with this piece of code under:

```
public enum UserSkills {

    HARD_WORKNG("HARD_WORKNG"),
    ON_TIME("ON_TIME"),
    HONEST("HONEST");

    public final String value;

    UserSkills(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name() + "[" + value + "]";
    }

    public static List < UserSkills > of (String userSkills) {
        notNull(userSkills, "userSkills cannot be null");
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .flatMap(s - > {
                if (values().length > 3) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("you can only choose up to 3 user skills", userSkills));
                } else {

                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to finish it any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why use streams for this? It would seem to be so much simpler to not do this.

Comment: Okay, what do you have in mind?

Comment: That all depends on your program. And also, it seems a bit odd to have user input validation in the enum itself as that seems to go against the "single responsibility rule"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the method `of` should accept a vararg `String ... userSkills` (or the input String should be split somehow to identify multiple enum values):

```java
public static List<UserSkills> of (String ... userSkills) {
    List<UserSkills> result = Arrays.stream(userSkills)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(UserSkills::valueOf) // throws IllegalArgumentException no enum constant
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    if (result.size() > 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only 2 skills can be selected");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```java
List<UserSkills> skills = UserSkills.of(null, "HARD_WORKNG", "HONEST", "HARD_WORKNG", "ON_TIME");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only 2 skills can be selected
```

```java
List<UserSkills> skills = UserSkills.of(null, "HARD_WORKNG", "HONEST", "HARD_WORKNG");
System.out.println(skills);
```

Output:

```
[HARD_WORKNG[HARD_WORKNG], HONEST[HONEST]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just one question. This line of code `.map(PlayerSkills::valueOf)`gives an error that valueOf is ambiguous

Comment: Is it a warning?  I tested [online](https://ideone.com/Mv1s5g). it ran successfully.

Comment: My bad, yes, it works correctly. Thank you very much for your answer :)